# Windows 10 UAC and compiling C++

Tags: windows, uac, c++

I'm trying to code some basic c++ on atom ide or notepad++. I followed some tutorials on youtube and I downloaded the mingw c++ compiler and it has installed properly (I think) and I've added it to my variable path, in my laptop, with my administrator account.

However, I'm trying to run a "Hello World!" example, but my cmd line errors and and says, "access is denied." I have tried to allow full control to my own user account, but when I get to the widows dialog box, it's greyed out. It's like un-editable. So, being the administrator of this laptop, how does the security dialog show everything as being greyed out. I don't understand if I'm the administrator, by default, shouldn't I be allowed to compile and run code? My feeling is that onedrive is messing it up somehow...

any ideas on how to proceed?

thx for any help,

windows 10, 1903

Comment: Is AppLocker enabled? What virusscanner is in use? Either one of them could cause this by blocking software from running in (what they think is) an  "untrusted" location.

Answer (score -1):

It was McAfee antivirus. You have to pause active scanning and then run your c++ code.

Ugh!

Comment: Look into the narrowest posssible whitelist settings to allow McAfee to remain running while allowing the code to run.